# Game Theory - Rubinstein bargaining

Tags: game-theory

may I ask you how to solve this problem?

What will be the outcome of infinite Rubinstein bargaining if the first mover (player A) has outside option with utility M and the second mover (player B) has zero outside option.

Thank you!

Comment: Give more context. Do players have the same discount factor? Is $M >0$? Presumably you are referring to the alternating offers protocol?

Comment: I think that we can assume same discount factor for both players and non-zero outside option for player A which is M>0.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not more informations than it was written but I think that these two assumptions holds there.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_i$ be the amount offered by $j$ to $i$. Using the Shaked-Sutton shortcut in the standard symmetric version (same discount factor, zero outside option), we derive the two equations
$$m_1 = \delta (1-m_2) \mbox{ and } m_2 = \delta (1 - m_1)$$
and find $m_i = \delta/(1+\delta)$.

If $1$ has an outside option $M$, you need to change the first equation in
$$m_1 = \max\{ \delta (1-m_2), M \}$$
and solve accordingly. (Distinguish two cases, depending on $\delta (1-m_2) \gtrless M$.